# How to use group by <<colName>> properly in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Below is the data in my table

```
| count(*) | system |
|        2 | sys1   |
|        7 | sys2   |
|        6 | sys1   |
```

I want the output as below

```
| count(*) | system |
|        8 | sys1   |
|        7 | sys2   |
```

How do I do that?
Below is the query I am using. Can anyone tell me what is wrong in this?

```
select * from 

(select count(*),system from tbl1 where creationDate < CURDATE() AND creationDate >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY group by system 

UNION ALL 

select count(*),system from tbl2 where creationDate < CURDATE() AND creationDate >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY group by system) as tbl3 group by system;
```

Comment: what are tbl1 and tbl2? GROUP BY is all you need for one table, it is not clear what you need from the second part of the question. And you def need SUM not COUNT

Comment: Ok Sorry probably my query is incorrect. I hope my question is clear. Can you please help me with the proper query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a sub-query to achieve this:

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(Total) AS `Count`, system
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total, system FROM tbl1 
            WHERE creationDate < CURDATE() 
              AND creationDate >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY GROUP BY system
    UNION ALL
     SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total, system FROM tbl2 
            WHERE creationDate < CURDATE() 
              AND creationDate >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY GROUP BY system
) A
GROUP BY system
```

OUTPUT:

```
| COUNT | system |
|     8 | sys1   |
|     7 | sys2   |
```

Comment: @Alnitak - See [the revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16373573/revisions) OP removed it by editing.

Comment: @user1815809 - Glad to hear that. BTW have a look at our [Markdown Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) before asking or answering a question. :)